# Checking if the checkboxes are selected or not

Tags: python, selenium

I am using this function to check the multiple number of checkboxes:

```
def checkMultipleCheckoxes(self, values):
        for i in values:
            checkboxes = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@value='%s']"% i)
            if not checkboxes.is_selected():
                checkboxes.click()
```

then I am using this in another function to check if these checkboxes are selected if not then i select them:

```
self.checkMultipleCheckoxes(["13084", "13087", "13088", "13085", "15607", "15608", "15606", "15637", "15605"])
```

However, I am not sure what I am doing wrong - this is the error I get

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_selected''
```

Comment: Looks like your xpath is not unique because of which list of elements is being returned rather than a single element.

Comment: @JayeshDoolani 
my xpath will be different based on the values i am passing in self.checkMultipleChecboxes ?

Comment: @JayeshDoolani The xpath doesn't really matter.. what matters is that it's using `.find_elements_*()` which always returns a collection even if the collection only contains a single element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`checkboxes` is a collection of elements (not a single element) since you are getting the return from `.find_elements_*` (plural). You would want to loop through the collection and then check each element to see if `is_selected()` is `true`. Also, you are using `isSelected()` which is Java... you want python which is [`is_selected()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_selected).

Comment: i am sorry but i do not understand the first part

Comment: When you use `.find_elements_by_xpath()` it returns a collection of elements not just a single element. That's why you are getting the error because the collection doesn't have a method `is_selected()`. `is_selected()` applies to a single element not a collection. You should read the python/Selenium documentation for these `find_elements_*()` methods. `find_element()` returns a single element where `find_elements()` returns a collection of elements.